# Add comment to specific issue

Tags: java

I'm making a Issue Tracking System but I'm stuck at adding comments to a specific issue you recieve from an ID.
I want to be able to get the specific issue from a unique ID that's already stored in a ArrayList(done), and then write a comment that's gonna be saved on that specific issue(in it's own ArrayList maybe?), so when I later on shows the information about that specific issue, the comments will also be shown with the timestamp as the comment was made.

```java
public class Class2 {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<Issue> issues = new ArrayList<Issue>();

    public void retrieveIssue() {

        System.out.println("Write the ID of the issue you want to show:");
        String inputNewID = input.nextLine();
        boolean isIssueFound = false;
        for (Issue issue : issues) {
            if (inputNewID.equals(issue.getID())) {
                isIssueFound = true;
                System.out.println("ID: " + issue.getID() + "\nName: " + issue.getIssueName() + "\nDate: " + issue.getLocalDate() + "\nComment: " + issue.getIssueComment() + "\nStatus: " + issue.getIssueStatus());
            }
        }

        if (!isIssueFound) {
            System.out.println("False ID. Try again.");
        }
    }

    public void commentIssue() {
        System.out.println("Write the ID of the issue you want to comment:");
        String inputNewID = input.nextLine();
        boolean isIssueFound = false;
        for (Issue issue : issues) {
            if (inputNewID.equals(issue.getID())) {
                isIssueFound = true;
            }
            System.out.println("Vad vill du kommentera?");
            String issueComment = input.nextLine();
            Issue comment = new Issue(issueComment);
        }

        if (!isIssueFound) {
            System.out.println("False ID. Try again.");
        }
    }
}
```

```java
public class Issue {
    private String ID;
    private String issueName;
    private String localDate;
    private String issueStatus;
    private String issueComment;

    public Issue (String ID, String issueName, String issueStatus) {
        this.ID = ID;
        this.issueName = issueName;
        this.localDate = new Date().toString();
        this.issueStatus = issueStatus;
    }

    public Issue(String issueComment) {
        this.issueComment = issueComment;
    }

    public void setID(String ID) {
        this.ID = ID;
    }

    public void setIssueName(String issueName) {
        this.issueName = issueName;
    }

    public void setIssueStatus(String issueStatus) {
        this.issueStatus = issueStatus;
    }

    public void setLocalDate(String localDate) {
        this.localDate = localDate;
    }

    public void setIssueComment(String issueComment) {
        this.issueComment = issueComment;
    }

    public String getID() {
        return this.ID;
    }

    public String getIssueName() {
        return this.issueName;
    }

    public String getLocalDate() {
        return this.localDate;
    }

    public String getIssueStatus() {
        return this.issueStatus;
    }

    public String getIssueComment() {
        return this.issueComment;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are creating a `new Issue(issueComment);`. That means you will have one Issue (with just a comment) per comment. That is not desired, most likely. You need to restructure the class `Issue` and give it a `private List<String> comments;` as an attribute instead of a single `String`. By doing so, you can provide a method `addComment(String comment)` that just adds a new comment to an already existing `Issue`.

Answer (score 1):

In order to make your class `Issue` be able to store **more than a single comment**, you have to provide a suitable data structure for the comments, a single `String` is not sufficient. If you want to add a comment, provide a method for that. See the class `Issue` slightly changed:

```java
public class Issue {
    private String ID;
    private String issueName;
    private String localDate;
    private String issueStatus;
    private List<String> issueComments; // this is the first change

    public Issue (String ID, String issueName, String issueStatus) {
        this.ID = ID;
        this.issueName = issueName;
        this.localDate = new Date().toString();
        this.issueStatus = issueStatus;
        this.issueComments = new ArrayList<>(); // the list needs to be initialized
    }

    // this getter gives you all the comments of an instance of Issue
    public List<String> getIssueComments() {
        return issueComments;
    }

    // omitted other getters and setters for brevity

    /**
     * Adds a new comment to the collection of issue comments
     */
    public void addComment(String comment) {
        issueComments.add(comment);
    }
}
```

In the `commentIssue()` method of your `Class2`, you will have to use the current `Issue` in your enhanced `for` loop and add the new comment. See the code comments in the class below:

```java
public class Class2 {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<Issue> issues = new ArrayList<Issue>();

    public void retrieveIssue() {
        System.out.println("Write the ID of the issue you want to show:");
        String inputNewID = input.nextLine();
        boolean isIssueFound = false;
        for (Issue issue : issues) {
            if (inputNewID.equals(issue.getID())) {
                isIssueFound = true;
                System.out.println("ID: " + issue.getID() 
                        + "\nName: " + issue.getIssueName() 
                        + "\nDate: " + issue.getLocalDate() 
                        + "\nComment: " + issue.getIssueComment() 
                        + "\nStatus: " + issue.getIssueStatus());
            }
        }

        if (!isIssueFound) {
            System.out.println("False ID. Try again.");
        }
    }

    public void commentIssue() {
        System.out.println("Write the ID of the issue you want to comment:");
        String inputNewID = input.nextLine();
        boolean isIssueFound = false;
        for (Issue issue : issues) {
            if (inputNewID.equals(issue.getID())) {
                issueFound = true;
                System.out.println("Vad vill du kommentera?");
                String issueComment = input.nextLine();
                /*
                 * No need for a new instance of Issue here,
                 * just store the comment in the collection of comments 
                 * of this specific instance of Issue
                 */
                issue.add(issueComment);
            }

            if (!issueFound) {
                System.out.println("False ID. Try again.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, sir!!

But.. I receive an error with `issue.getIssueComment()`..

Comment: Do you still have that getter? Remove it, the class attribute is now called `issueComments`.

Comment: My bad.. Forgot the s..

Now, it works!

And the only thing left is to also get the timestamp of the submit of the comment and print that with the comment.. I haven't tried anything yet though.

Comment: @GudenLjunkan Well, I got an idea about that, but it is really important for you to think about it yourself first. Find out how to use a `Map` instead of a `List` and find out how to get a timestamp. If you are stuck you will be welcome to ask another question or edit this one.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to assign the comment with the issue with the specified ID, you got to add the comment using the `setIssueComment` method that you have implemented in the Issue class.

Instead of doing

```
Issue comment = new Issue(issueComment);
```

Try

```
issue.setIssueComment(issueComment);
```

And that should update the issue comment of the issue you looked for.

Comment: That will replace every comment stored before.

Comment: You also have to to move the logic in the if-statement. But your current data structure does not support multiple comments if that is what you want.

Comment: Yep, as deHaar said, it replaces every comment that I have commented before..
And, if I'm adding another issue, and then wants to add a comment to one of the issues.. It loops through the ArrayList so that I'll have to add comments to every issue one at a time and not only the issue with the ID I have entered.